# Why aren't certain file types updating in the document library?

Tags: document, library, file

For the past couple of weeks, I've been updating my SharePoint subsite files by uploading them to the document library. It's been working fine until after this weekend. JavaScript, CSS, and various image file formats will keep reverting back to the previous saved version from before the weekend, even though the file size changes and there's a new entry in the version history. The only thing is the actual file contents don't update.

I've tried deleting these files and reuploading them, but to no avail. The only thing that works is if I upload them under a different file name, so I suspect this might be a caching issue. I know for sure it's not browser caching because I've cleared and done Ctrl + F5 multiple times.

One thing I've noticed is that it doesn't happen with HTML and .txt files. Those file formats seem to update as per normal.

Does anyone have any insight on the matter?

Comment: So, if you open e.g. one of your CSS files, which seems to have reverted, does its contents still include the new definitions which are just not displayed on SharePoint when the file is referenced there? And there are no new version entries that would be "automatically" created after the initial update of a revisited version of the file?

Comment: No, if I open the file, it still shows the old contents. The only way you can tell it's a new version is the upload time, version number, and file size change. But if you open the file, it has old contents, and referencing the file in HTML uses the old contents.